# SET BIGINT fieldname value to 0 automatically if inserting empty string

Tags: mysql, insert, integer

How do I do something like :

`INSERT INTO tablename SET customer_id = '' WHERE <condition>;`

customer_id is BIGINT NULL Default NULL

But when I execute `SET customer_id = ''` it gives

**Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'customer_id' at row 1**

Comment: But WHY you try to insert string into numeric column?

Comment: I wrote a migration script to load relevant fields' data data from an older database and created INSERT statements to load into the new table where instead of varchar or text is given for numbers since the new table's columns are Integer instead of varchar / text.

Comment: so, "fix the migration script" is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Becaust is is a Integer field you cannot fill that field with a (empty) "" string value.

If you insert a (empty) record without specifying the customer_id field it will default to NULL (just do not specify it in the insert).

If you want to clear out the field you can fill the files with a NULL value like:

INSERT INTO tablename SET customer_id = NULL WHERE ;

If you want to put a 0 value into that field:

INSERT INTO tablename SET customer_id = 0 WHERE ;

Comment: `$q = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM oldTablename"); ... $sub_total = ($row["sub_total"] == '' ? 0 : str_replace( ',', '', $row["sub_total"]));....echo "INSERT INTO newTableName SET id = NULL, sub_total = '".$sub_total."',` - I was hoping not to do `$row["sub_total"] == '' ? 0`

Comment: Maybe:
 ... $sub_total = ($row["sub_total"] == '' ? 'NULL' : str_replace( ',', '', $row["sub_total"]));
 ....echo "INSERT INTO newTableName SET id = NULL, sub_total = ".$sub_total.", 
will work? (remove the quotes in the INSERT as $sub_total as it is a number, not a string),

Comment: Well:
 - I was hoping not to do $row["sub_total"] == '' ? 0
sorry for that ;)